# Dynamically displaying the column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here, I have 10 columns i.e., `answer1, answer2, answer3, ..., answer10` in the table `MgAnswer`.
I have to check whether each column value is present or not. Only if it present,then I have to display it in the page.

Im giving column names dynamically within for loop

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
   <% if MgAnswer."answer#{i}".present? %>
      <%= MgAnswer."answer#{i}" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Im ending up with Syntax error.

Comment: What is that syntax error?

Comment: can you check it as ` nil?`

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: end is missing each loop

Comment: You are missing an `<% end %>`, that is why you are getting the syntax error.

Comment: yes...but still Im getting the error @uzaif

Comment: did you get same error?

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: what is this `MgAnswer."answer#{i}"`?

Comment: it leads to syntax error

Comment: `MgAnswer` is the table and `answer#{i}` is the column name which will return `answer1,answer2....` in the loop @МалъСкрылевъ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should seem like the following:

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <%= MgAnswer.send("answer#{i}") %>
<% end %>
```

Since ruby can't evaluate line as `MgAnswer."method"`. Also you can just skip `if` condition, because it will be evaluated to empty string `""`.

Comment: @MikhailChuprynski if it is blank, it just show "".

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed dynamically invoke methods in ruby, but this is not the syntax. Instead do

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <% if MgAnswer.public_send("answer#{i}").present? %>
    <%= MgAnswer.public_send("answer#{i}") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```